# Combine isfield and ~isempty within the same test

Tags: matlab

I have written a lot of Matlab code using structs and I have the following problem recurring.

I often need to test if a field exists and is not empty. So far, my solution is:

```
if isfield(var, 'field')
    if ~isempty(var.field)
    ...
```

when one or the other test fails I need to perform the very same action. In these cases the solution is far from being elegant. For example:

```
if isfield(var, 'field')
    if ~isempty(var.field)
       fieldOk = true;
    else
       fieldOk = false;
    end
else
    fieldOk = false;
end
```

A better solution would be to do both tests at once. I could write a function that wraps all this but I am wondering if there is a native Matlab solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
if isfield(var, 'field') && ~isempty(var.field)
   fieldOk = true;
else
   fieldOk = false;
end
```

The logical operator `X && Y` just evaluates `Y` if `X` is true.
[Have a look here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html). Therefore it's exactly what you need. But you may have to turn it around:

```
if ~isempty(var.field) && isfield(var, 'field')
```

Comment: That's not working. If field does not exist in var, Matlab returns: `Reference to non-existent field`

Comment: I don't know why I though that this didn't work. Actually I just realized that it works !! Thank's a lot.